# Is it possible to match this event with an AWS EventBridge pattern?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-codebuild, aws-event-bridge

I'm trying to create an EventBridge Event Pattern that matches a CodeBuild state change only when a specific string is present in "phase-context" of one of the objects within the "phases" array.

I've been unable to find an example of how to match a single objects property within an array of objects. Is it possible? I know I could look to match a CodeBuild phases change event instead but want to avoid that if possible.

I have marked in the string I want to match in the example CodeBuild state change event below:

```
{
  "version": "0",
  "id": "c030038d-8c4d-6141-9545-00ff7b7153EX",
  "detail-type": "CodeBuild Build State Change",
  "source": "aws.codebuild",
  "account": "123456789012",
  "time": "2017-09-01T16:14:28Z",
  "region": "us-west-2",
  "resources":[
    "arn:aws:codebuild:us-west-2:123456789012:build/my-sample-project:8745a7a9-c340-456a-9166-edf953571bEX"
  ],
  "detail":{
    "build-status": "SUCCEEDED",
    "project-name": "my-sample-project",
    "build-id": "arn:aws:codebuild:us-west-2:123456789012:build/my-sample-project:8745a7a9-c340-456a-9166-edf953571bEX",
    "additional-information": {
      "artifact": {
        "md5sum": "da9c44c8a9a3cd4b443126e823168fEX",
        "sha256sum": "6ccc2ae1df9d155ba83c597051611c42d60e09c6329dcb14a312cecc0a8e39EX",
        "location": "arn:aws:s3:::codebuild-123456789012-output-bucket/my-output-artifact.zip"
      },
      "environment": {
        "image": "aws/codebuild/standard:4.0",
        "privileged-mode": false,
        "compute-type": "BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL",
        "type": "LINUX_CONTAINER",
        "environment-variables": []
      },
      "timeout-in-minutes": 60,
      "build-complete": true,
      "initiator": "MyCodeBuildDemoUser",
      "build-start-time": "Sep 1, 2017 4:12:29 PM",
      "source": {
        "location": "codebuild-123456789012-input-bucket/my-input-artifact.zip",
        "type": "S3"
      },
      "logs": {
        "group-name": "/aws/codebuild/my-sample-project",
        "stream-name": "8745a7a9-c340-456a-9166-edf953571bEX",
        "deep-link": "https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-west-2#logEvent:group=/aws/codebuild/my-sample-project;stream=8745a7a9-c340-456a-9166-edf953571bEX"
      },
      "phases": [
        {
          "phase-context": [],
          "start-time": "Sep 1, 2017 4:12:29 PM",
          "end-time": "Sep 1, 2017 4:12:29 PM",
          "duration-in-seconds": 0,
          "phase-type": "SUBMITTED",
          "phase-status": "SUCCEEDED"
        },
        {
          "phase-context": [],
          "start-time": "Sep 1, 2017 4:12:29 PM",
          "end-time": "Sep 1, 2017 4:13:05 PM",
          "duration-in-seconds": 36,
          "phase-type": "PROVISIONING",
          "phase-status": "SUCCEEDED"
        },
        {
          "phase-context": [],
          "start-time": "Sep 1, 2017 4:13:05 PM",
          "end-time": "Sep 1, 2017 4:13:10 PM",
          "duration-in-seconds": 4,
          "phase-type": "DOWNLOAD_SOURCE",
          "phase-status": "SUCCEEDED"
        },
        {
          "phase-context": [],
          "start-time": "Sep 1, 2017 4:13:10 PM",
          "end-time": "Sep 1, 2017 4:13:10 PM",
          "duration-in-seconds": 0,
          "phase-type": "INSTALL",
          "phase-status": "SUCCEEDED"
        },
        {
          "phase-context": [],
          "start-time": "Sep 1, 2017 4:13:10 PM",
          "end-time": "Sep 1, 2017 4:13:10 PM",
          "duration-in-seconds": 0,
          "phase-type": "PRE_BUILD",
          "phase-status": "SUCCEEDED"
        },
        {
          "phase-context": [
            "something here" <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< THIS STRING 
           ],
          "start-time": "Sep 1, 2017 4:13:10 PM",
          "end-time": "Sep 1, 2017 4:14:21 PM",
          "duration-in-seconds": 70,
          "phase-type": "BUILD",
          "phase-status": "SUCCEEDED"
        },
        {
          "phase-context": [],
          "start-time": "Sep 1, 2017 4:14:21 PM",
          "end-time": "Sep 1, 2017 4:14:21 PM",
          "duration-in-seconds": 0,
          "phase-type": "POST_BUILD",
          "phase-status": "SUCCEEDED"
        },
        {
          "phase-context": [],
          "start-time": "Sep 1, 2017 4:14:21 PM",
          "end-time": "Sep 1, 2017 4:14:21 PM",
          "duration-in-seconds": 0,
          "phase-type": "UPLOAD_ARTIFACTS",
          "phase-status": "SUCCEEDED"
        },
         {
          "phase-context": [],
          "start-time": "Sep 1, 2017 4:14:21 PM",
          "end-time": "Sep 1, 2017 4:14:26 PM",
          "duration-in-seconds": 4,
          "phase-type": "FINALIZING",
          "phase-status": "SUCCEEDED"
        },
        {
          "start-time": "Sep 1, 2017 4:14:26 PM",
          "phase-type": "COMPLETED"
        }
      ]
    },
    "current-phase": "COMPLETED",
    "current-phase-context": "[]",
    "version": "1"
  }
}
```

Comment: I posted something along these lines yesterday, might help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67766065/259122

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EventBridge supports value matches within array (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/arrays-in-eventbridge-event-patterns.html). I'm not certain but AFAIK it doesn't support patterns within an array. To be sure, I'd recommend trying out the filters specified in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/content-filtering-with-event-patterns.html within a rule pattern.

If this fails, you would need to setup a lambda (or fargate / ec2) to transform the input before calling put-events again.